# SwiftUI Why does "return" causes "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't understand why this error happened [Unable to infer complex closure return type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq4Pn.png)

But after I remove `return` it works completely fine [without it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Oph.png)
Can someone explain what happened here, I thought we can only use implicit return when there is only a single line for that closure.

Comment: Post code as text and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

In the attached screenshot -
[image]

`return` means that as soon as you enter the first iteration of the `ForEach`, you are returning that result.

When you don't have a `return` keyword in there, you are letting `SwiftUI` handle the return type implicitly.

**I thought we can only use implicit return when there is only a single line for that closure.**

> The return type is complex in this case. GeometryReader<Whatever_Is_Nested_Inside>
> It is still a single return point for this method though.